# How to search datatable using column name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to search and filter data in datatable based on two columns.
Below is the code that I am using for search and redrawing the datatable.
(http://live.datatables.net/hapijuri/1/edit)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [  
      { title: 'title0', name: 'name0'},
      { title: 'title1', name: 'name1'},
      { title: 'title2', name: 'name2'},
      { title: 'title3', name: 'name3'},
      { title: 'title4', name: 'name4'},
      { title: 'title5', name: 'name5'},
    ]
  });
  table.column(1).search('Software Engineer')
      .column(0).search('Bradley Greer').draw();
} );
```

The problem with this code is that it works on the column number (or index) and not on column name, however I have the column names on which I want to search.

Is there any way to search based on column name instead of index in datatables jquery?

Edit: Providing additional details to make sure I am able to present the question well.
So I have a datatable shown on UI and I am building a pivot table (using pivottable.js) in another tab using the datatable data.

On clicking the numbers in the pivot, I want the datatable data on the UI to be filtered so that it shows only those rows which are relevant to the number being clicked in pivot.

I am getting the column name and value corresponding to that number from pivot. I just need to search those column values in the datatable and show the filter the datatable accordingly.

As pointed in the example link that I shared, I am able to search through the data based on column index and the same is getting reflected on the UI. 
What I am looking for is searching based on column name instead of column value.

Answer (score 3):

Search a datatable using the column name

```
var table = $('#datatable-name').DataTable();

table.column('columnname:name').search("keyword").draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

For preventing a column being searched from table you have to add `searchable:false`. by default value of `searchable & orderable` is `true`.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [  
        { title: 'title0', name: 'name0', "searchable": true},
        { title: 'title1', name: 'name1'},
        { title: 'title2', name: 'name2'},
        { title: 'title3', name: 'name3'},
        { title: 'title4', name: 'name4'},
        { title: 'title5', name: 'name5'},
    ]      
});
```

no need to add below code unless you have server side data processing.

```
 table.column(1).search('Software Engineer')
     .column(0).search('Bradley Greer').draw();
```

Comment: I need to apply filter based on specific columns via code and the datatable on the UI should be filtered accordingly.

Comment: Say, in a 5 columns datatable, I need to apply search where column1 = test1 and column2 = test2. The datatable on the UI should show the filtered data accordingly. I am able to achieve it but using index number of column. I want to be able to search based on column name instead of column number through my javascript code.

Comment: if you only need to search column1 , column2 add `searchable:true` to those.

Comment: @Sreeraj_ms Edited the question to explain it better. I am not looking for a search field on the UI. I am looking for filtering the data on the UI programmatically based on column name and column value.

Answer (score 0):

### Make column to searchable true not required

No, it is not necessary to set the searchable option to true for a column in order to search within that column. By default, all columns in a DataTable are searchable, unless you explicitly set the searchable option to false for a specific column.

The searchable option allows you to control whether a column should be included in the global search functionality provided by DataTables. If set to true, the column will be included in the search. If set to false, the column will be excluded from the search.

Here's an example of how to configure the searchable option for a column when initializing the DataTable:

```html
var table = $('#yourTable').DataTable({
  columns: [
    { searchable: false }, // This column will be excluded from search
    null, // This column will be included in search (default behavior)
    null // This column will be included in search (default behavior)
  ]
});
```

### For Search a particular value

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

  // Add event listener to the table column(s)
  $('#myTable thead th').on('click', function() {
    var columnIndex = $(this).index(); // Index of the clicked column
    var searchValue = $(this).text().trim(); // Clicked column name

    // Redraw the DataTable with the new search query
    table.columns().search('').draw(); // Clear previous search
    table.column(columnIndex).search(searchValue).draw(); // Apply new search
  });
});
```